# what is the best way to exchange 2 registers in Verilog

Tags: verilog

i know several ways to exchange 2 registers :
using 3 xors, using register, using multiplexer, etc...
how can we make conditional exchange, it should take as less code as possible and work as fast as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is probably best in Verilog - just assign them to each other using non-blocking assignments

```
a <= b;
b <= a;
```

The synthesizer will do the right thing.

Comment: Since you have blocking assignments here this would actually have the effect of making a=b rather than swapping them.

Comment: Doh, that's what I get for answering Verilog questions without checking them really carefully!

Answer (score 2):

[Tripple-XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) is a software trick used to exchange register values on a sequential machine where a direct register exchange instruction (eg. x86 `XCHG`) is not available. The XOR instructions cannot be executed concurrently as they each depend on the previous output, so it takes three instruction cycles.

With Verilog you are describing hardware, so you exchange two register's values in a single cycle by assignment. This will infer a load path for both registers from each other's output.

```
if (swap) begin
  a <= b;
  b <= a;
end
```

You mention multiplexers - only if there is another load path, multiplexers and control logic will be instantiated as required, eg. some swap/increment device would have  multiplexers since `a`  can be loaded with either `b` or `a+1`.

```
if (swap) begin
  a <= b;
  b <= a;
end else begin
  a <= a+1;
end
```

Comment: I would omit the 'else' part of this entirely and I'm not sure where the +1 part came from, but this is otherwise the way I would do it.

Comment: If you wanted just a swap/noswap deal, you could write something like this.

if (swap) begin
  a <= b;
  b <= a;
end else begin
  a <= a;
  b <= b;
end

Answer (score 1):

```
a <= b;
b <= a;
```

That's all you need to do.